# WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile - Admin Center

Tags: websphere

I'm newbie.

I installed WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile using IBM Installation Manager.

To access adminCenter-1.0, tried with following commands:

```
featureManager.bat install adminCenter-1.0
```

and got error as

> CWWKF1009E: The file adminCenter-1.0 does not exist.

How to enable and access adminCenter?

Thanks

Comment: What version do you have installed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the installUtility to download and install the feature.

To install the feature from the command line type:
   `bin/installUtility install adminCenter-1.0`

See more details here : 
https://developer.ibm.com/assets/wasdev/#asset/features-com.ibm.websphere.appserver.adminCenter-1.0

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to provide this as a comment, but I don't have enough 'reputation' :S

FeatureManager should still work.  InstallUtility is superseding featureManager's install capabiltiies, but featureManager is still supported.  Could you provide the output of 'bin/productInfo version' and the featureManager command you used?

FYI, there's a similar thread [here](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/14379/download-install-a-feature-in-liberty-profile.html), which might provide some answers, but it's a little out of date, so some of the suggestions around proxy support have better solutions now.

Regards, Graham.